# Html.Serialize return NullReferenceException

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ViewModel like

```
namespace ViewModel
{
    [Serializable]
    public class TestViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Also, I have one action method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    TestViewModel model = new TestViewModel
    {
        Id = -1,
        Name = "Some name",
        Description = "Some description"
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

And my View something like this:

```
@using Microsoft.Web.Mvc
@model ViewModel.TestViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    Html.Serialize("model", Model, SerializationMode.EncryptedAndSigned);
    //....Editor fields
}
```

In line "Html.Serialize("model", Model,  SerializationMode.EncryptedAndSigned);" debugger is stopped and returns exception "object reference not set to an instance of an object" (NullReferenceException). Although, the Model is not null and contains initial values.

I use ASP.Net MVC 3(Razor) and stack trace is below:

```
in Microsoft.Web.Mvc.SerializationExtensions.SerializeInternal(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
String name, Object data, SerializationMode mode, Boolean useViewData, MvcSerializer
serializer) 
in Microsoft.Web.Mvc.SerializationExtensions.SerializeInternal(HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
String name, Object data, SerializationMode mode, Boolean useViewData)
in Microsoft.Web.Mvc.SerializationExtensions.Serialize(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String
name, Object data, SerializationMode mode)
in ASP._Page_Views_Wizard_Index_cshtml.Execute()
in c:\Projects\TestProject\Views\Wizard\Index.cshtml:line 15
in System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
in System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
in System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage()
in System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
in System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext,
TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
in System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer,
Object instance)
in System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter
writer)
in System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
in System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext
controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
in System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.
<>c__DisplayClass1c.InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()
in System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, 
ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
```

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: You'll have to provide more details about the error you're seeing, such as a stack trace, the version of MVC you're using, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
@Html.Serialize("model", Model, SerializationMode.EncryptedAndSigned)
```

if you want hidden field with model on form.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem in this part of code? I am using exactly your code with update that is in my answer and it works. May be you have some ActionFilters? Could you show your global.asax.cs? Do you have any attributes on controller class or action method?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had assembly reference to Mvc2Futures ("Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll"). But when I changed the reference to Mvc3Futures ("Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll") all work fine.
Thanks a lot.